# How do I map only if the iterable isn't null in Scala?

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to retrieve a list of servers from a configuration file in the Play framework. Currently I have the following code:

```
val servers: List[Server] = {
  val servers = ConfigFactory.load().getConfigList("servers") map { s =>
    Server(s.getString("ip"), s.getString("port")) }
  servers.toList
}
```

A problem arises when `"servers"` doesn't exist in the configuration file. In this case, `ConfigFactory.load().getConfigList("servers") == null`, so the `map` operation causes a `NullPointerException`. An easy workaround would be to store the result of `ConfigFactory.load().getConfigList("servers")`, and branch on its result.

This approach doesn't feel idiomatic to me. Is there a way that I can only `map` if the preceding expression isn't `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Java API for Play.

```
play.api.Play.application.configuration.getConfigList
```

Would call `def
getConfigList(path: String): Option[List[Configuration]]` which you could then use getOrElse on

server_list = ConfigFactory.load().getConfigList("servers").getOrElse(List())

Note that `play.api.Play.application` is deprecated. As pointed out by the OP the new code to retrieve this value should be `server_list = ConfigFactory.load().getConfigList("servers")`

Comment: Just found `com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory`, so the resulting change should be `val server_list = ConfigFactory.load().getConfigList("servers")`. I'll update this in my question then remove this comment.

Comment: Cool, also realized you can't flatten `Option[List[T]]` but you can use `getOrElse(List())` to end up with `List[T]` that's empty in the case of None

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this for now.

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

//...

val server_list = ConfigFactory.load().getConfigList("servers")

val servers: List[Server] = server_list match {
  case null => List[Server]()
  case _ => val servers = server_list map { s =>
    Server(s.getString("ip"), s.getString("port")) }
  servers.toList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try wrapping an Option around the first call:

```
val server_list = Option(play.Play.application().configuration().getConfigList("servers"))
```

This should return None instead of null. Then you can use .getOrElse(List.empty).map...